# Do all $L^{\infty}(\mu)$ spaces have the Grothendieck property?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

Consider $L_{\infty}(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$, where $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ is any measure space. Does it it have the Grothendieck property? If the measure space is localizable, then it is true. The Bourgain-Delbaen space is a separable $\mathcal{L}_\infty$ space with the Schur property and since its bidual is complemented in  $L_{\infty}(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ for some measure space, this could be an example  of an $L_{\infty}(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ without the Grothendieck-property.

Comment: The Encyclopedia of Mathematics lists $L_\infty(\mu)$ as examples of Grothendieck spaces, without any conditions. I guess you should check the references they cite, see http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Grothendieck_space&oldid=15530.

Comment: Since the Encyclopedia of Mathematics is not explicit in the references for $L^\infty$, consider this: a generic $L^\infty$ as vector lattice of self-adjoint elements is Dedekind $\sigma$-complete (and complete iff localizable); its spectrum as $C^*$-algebra is then $\sigma$-stonean (see Berberian, Baer$^*$ rings, page 45 or Meyer-Nieberg, Banach lattices, page 54) and now see Ando or Seever cited by the Encyclopedia.

Comment: user46855, you should post that as the answer.